# smarty : assign var and scope root

Tags: scope, smarty, assign

I have a template in smarty like this :

- Template folder

  - home.tpl
  - article.tpl
  - category.tpl
  - var.tpl

In each template file (except var.tpl), i include the file var.tpl.
home.tpl have a structure in 1 column
article.tpl have a structure in 2 columns

My template files are like this (home example) :

```
{include file="$tpl_dir./var.tpl"}
<div class="span{$center_column}" id="center_column">
</div>
```

In order to change quickly the apparence of my website, i wrote the following lines in var.tpl :

```
{assign var=center_column_g value=['home'=>'12','article'=>'10'] scope="root"}
{assign var=center_column_default value='10' scope="root"}

{if $center_column_g[$page_name]}
{assign var=center_column value=$center_column_g[$page_name] scope="root"}
{else}
{assign var=center_column value=$center_column_default scope="root"}
{/if}
```

ps : $page_name is a global variable with the name of each template page.

So with var.tpl, if i can easy change the class of my div #center_column

I have a doubt with this code :

```
{if $center_column_g[$page_name]}
    {assign var=center_column value=$center_column_g[$page_name] scope="root"}
    {else}
    {assign var=center_column value=$center_column_default scope="root"}
    {/if}
```

Is it right to assign var center_column in the root scope ?